# How do I pass a value from localStorage to @PostMapping handler?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I use Spring Boot, Maven, Thymeleaf

The user goes to my .html page, enters a value, I put this value to localStorage, then I want to pass this value (maybe as @ModelAttribute) to @PostMapping method, and then... (whatever, send it to database for example)

For example, I want to get String **userLogin** value

```
@PostMapping("/inbox")
    public String doCreateMessage(@ModelAttribute("formData") CreateMessageFromData formData, @ModelAttribute("userLogin") String userLogin, Model model) {
        Message message = new Message(formData.getId(), formData.getMessage(), userLogin);
        messageRepository.save(message);
        return "redirect:/inbox";
    }
```

What do I type in my .html page?
I want to do sth like this:

```
<script>
...
let value = localStorage.getItem("senderName");
${userLogin} = value;
...
</script>
```

(it doesn't work of course)

I know I can get the value from user through input form like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="messageSender" th:field="*{sender}" />
```

But my value is in localStorage

I just couldn't find the answer on the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hidden input with the value from localStorage:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="messageSender" th:field="*{sender}" />
<script>
let value = localStorage.getItem("senderName");
document.getElementById("messageSender").value = value;
</script>
```

or fill it once you submit the form:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="messageSender" th:field="*{sender}" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='document.getElementById("messageSender").value = localStorage.getItem("senderName")' />
```